# What happened to Gideon on "The Flash"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, arrowverse, the-flash

The rather powerful, time sensitive, and literal deus ex machina was a stunning find by the team.

The team seems to be immune to the temporal fact of "unwinding Wells" assumably due to Star Labs being immune to it.

What became of Gideon? It seems strange that the team wouldn't try to at least be learning how to work with it.

It seems to have just become another television non-entity like Tiger, the Bradys' dog or Richie Cunningham's older brother.

Comment: I believe the reverse flash added Gideon into his suit when he was running around after being found out. So she probably got erased from time when he did.

Comment: She appeared in 'Invasion!' part 2. She was on the legends of tommorow ship was she not?

Answer (score 3):

Gideon disappeared at the end of Season 1 Episode 20, *"The Trap"* along with the Reverse-Flash suit once Eobard knew the jig was up. Gideon was next seen *off-hand* in Season  1 Episode 21, *"Grodd Lives"* when Eobard shows Eddie *the News Paper* from the projection in his hand. It was last mentioned in Season 2 Episode 1, *"The Man Who Saved Central City"*, re: the News Paper.

According to the [EW's interview with Executive Producer Andrew Kreisberg in October for the Premiere of season 2](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/10/06/flash-season-2-premiere-ronnie-raymond-spoilers):

> **EW:** Can Team Flash still turn to Wells’ (Tom Cavanagh) A.I. Gideon for answers?
>   **Kreisberg:** ***Gideon is no longer there.***

The Voice Actress for Gideon, Morena Baccarin, is also busy with a full time role on *Gotham*, so she may not even be available in the future.

---

> **Update:** As of S02E11 "The Reverse-Flash Returns", Gideon has returned with Eobard. They exist as a paradox outside of time, a ***Time line Remnant***.

---

Logically, Gideon was on Eobard when he was destroyed in time by Eddie's sacrifice. We know that the Reverse Flash could contain Gideon in his palm.

Personal theory: Eobard used Gideon's power core to recharge the Particle Accelerator in Star Labs. Note Cisco's reaction in Season 1 Episode 22, *"Rogue Air"*:

> Do you see a Power Button anywhere on this thing? Dude this is from the Future. ***It's Beyond Me***.

which mirrors *"The Trap"*:

> If I can get into it's operating system, maybe I can disable it's memory core. [Barry has Gideon reveal it.] *Nervous Laugh* Yeah, ***Nope***. [Gives up on that idea as the Core is too complex at first look.]

The Power Tube and Gideon's core also share the same blue flux look.

[image]

Comment: Her being gone after Eobard perished, doesn't of course prevent her from returning, after all, she was, or will have been (?), created by Barry. *cough cough*

Comment: @BMWurm of course that was in a timeline where the Particle Accelerator didn't explode, and Barry didn't become the flash until 2020.

Comment: @mike Cortana as in Microsoft's wannabe siri, or Halo's Cortana, which is a singular AI. And I don't want to add in about Rip's Gideon yet due to lack of info. It really confuses the situation.

Comment: @Mike that's what we don't have evidence for yet. If Gideon is just one copy, or a unique AI. The voice for Rip's AI makes it even more difficult, in universe. All Siri sound the same (in the US. There are multiple Siri voices, UK is male, Australia is a different woman)